# CAPM Model - SUR Model -

Tags: self-study, least-squares, generalized-least-squares, seemingly-unrelated-regressions

We know that the CAPM regression (for a asset i) is given by

$\ z_i = α_i1_T +$ $\beta_iz_m + ε_i = X∗θ_i + ε_i$

How can I show that the estimator of $\hat\alpha$ has the following distribution

$\hat\alpha$ ~ N ($\alpha$, $\alpha_m$ / T $\sum$)

with with am = 1 + $\hat\mu^2_m$/ $\hat\sigma^2_m$ ?

$\hat\mu^2_m$ = 1/T $\sum_{t=1}^T z_mt $

$\hat\sigma^2_m$= 1/T $\sum_{t=1}^T (z_mt-$ $\hat\mu_m)^2 $

Comment: Is this homework, or are you a practitioner?  I am asking because how I would answer would change.  Different audience results in a different concern.

Comment: @user25459: how would you explain it?

Comment: I just moved and I am looking through my boxes for a book.  All those proofs are in there.  My academic work is to show how these proofs have a math mistake in them and are wrong, so I want to use a book example so I do not accidentally show you the wrong answer.  They are in Cochrane's Asset Pricing.

Comment: Went through Cochrane's book. Do you happen to know which chapter it was? Could not find it.

Comment: Its in a box, so I am working from memory.  Still, looking, though if you don't see it, I would have to derive by hand.  I am prepping to teach six classes, don't think I'll end up with enough free time.

Comment: Went through it again; did not see it also in other Finance books

Comment: What kind of estimator is $\hat\alpha$? OLS? MLE (under which distribution)? Why do you have GLS and SUR tags?